# Listar Classes com Jar gerado

Tags: java, classes

Tenho uma classe que busca e lista as classes dentro do meu jar, sendo ele:

```
public static Class[] getClasses(String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    assert classLoader != null;
    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();
        dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
    }
    ArrayList<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    for (File directory : dirs) {
        classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
    }
    return classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]);
}

/**
 * Recursive method used to find all classes in a given directory and subdirs.
 *
 * @param directory   The base directory
 * @param packageName The package name for classes found inside the base directory
 * @return The classes
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
private static List<Class> findClasses(File directory, String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        return classes;
    }
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            assert !file.getName().contains(".");
            classes.addAll(findClasses(file, packageName + "." + file.getName()));
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            Class teste = Class.forName(packageName + '.' + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6));
            if (teste.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)){
                classes.add(Class.forName(packageName + '.' + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6)));
            }
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Quando executo na IDE ele funciona corretamente, quando gero o JAR e executo fora da IDE, ele da erro não localizando nenhuma Classe, alguem pode me ajudar como faço pra ele pesquisar dentro do jar já gerado?

Answer (score 0):

Essa implementação é baseada no lookup de diretórios/arquivos.class que simplesmente não existem quando você gera o jar. Coloque alguns prints no código que você irá notar a busca sendo efetuada em diretórios inexistentes(jar).

A propósito, essa implementação foi postada no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520344/8401730) e também no [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/get-all-classes-within-package), ambas contém comentários indicando que não funcionam em um "executable-jar".

Uma opção é utilizar o [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Exemplo:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.mypackage.scanner.ClassScanner
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ClassScanner:

```
public class ClassScanner {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {              
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.scanner", new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
        for(Class<? extends Object> cls : classes) {
           System.out.println(cls.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Gerando jar com Maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

Para testes adicionei uma classe chamada "User" dentro do mesmo package.

Execução:

```
java -jar scanner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

// output
com.mypackage.scanner.ClassScanner
com.mypackage.scanner.User
```